# How to render HTML file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486071/how-do-i-render-an-html-file-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520212/how-can-i-render-html-file-in-node-js) but they are quite different from my approach. I am creating a `widget` for `sisense` using javascript.

**MyWidget.js**

```
render: function (widget, args) {
  console.log("My calendar widget");

  var element = $(args.element);
  element.empty();

  var myText='<p>hello</p>';  <----------I WANT TO REPLACE THIS WITH HTML FILE

  // Add to the DOM
  element.append(myText);
}
```

And the HTML file is **styler.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Date Picker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CUSTOM<span>DATE</span>PICKER</h1>
    <div class="date-picker">
        <div class="selected-date"></div>
        <div class="dates">
            <div class="month">
                <div class="arrows prev-mth">&lt;</div>
                <div class="mth"></div>
                <div class="arrows next-mth">&gt;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="days"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new in javascript. Please tell me how to do it. I'm not sure Is it even possible or not.

I also tried doing with a string:

```
var myText='<h1>CUSTOM<span>DATE</span>PICKERs</h1>'
                        +'<div class=date-picker></div>'
    +'<div class=selected-date></div>';
    +   '<div class=dates>'
    +       '<div class=month>'
    +           '<div class=arrows prev-mth>&lt;'
    +           '</div>'
    +           '<div class=mth>'
    +           '</div>'
    +           '<div class="arrows next-mth">&gt;'
    +           '</div>'
    +       '</div>'
    +   '<div class=days>'
    +   '</div>'
    +   '</div>'
    +'</div>';
```

Comment: I think you get something wrong in HTML. Can you show how you'd like the final `HTML` to be?

Comment: I think you to research tutorials rather than asking on here.

Comment: You can `fetch` that file. Something like that https://stackoverflow.com/q/36631762/863110

Comment: Or if a fetch is not what you want, just put the html in a string?

Comment: @evolutionxbox. I tried doing that also. But there are so many tags that it looks very messed up and the code reviewer wasn't very happy with that style of coding.

Comment: Why not talk to your code reviewer about how to approach this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Many people don't have a *code reviewer*. Try to keep comments constructive

Comment: @charlietfl I’m aware of this. The answers to this question are vast and opinionated. If the OP has a code reviewer they should communicate and think of a solution that works for them.

Comment: @evolutionxbox. But Sir i cannot create a string. Please suggest some other approach.